# Need to select from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

So, my tables are as follows (Primary keys in each table are PhoneID, ManufacturerID and OSID. Foreign keys are marked with an asterisk before the name):

**Phones**

```
PhoneID
*ManufacturerID
Model
*OSID
Description
ScreenSize
Price
StockQuantity
StorageSize
Image
Thumbnail
IsFlagged
```

**Manufacturer**

```
ManufacturerID
Name
Details
Telephone
```

**OS**

```
OSID
Name
Company
Description
```

What I need to do is basically a query that will take the manufacturer name and phone model and other details and display it. Example:

If I have:

Samsung in the Manufacturer row from **Manufacturer**

Galaxy S3 in Model row from **Phones**

16GB in StorageSize row from **Phones**

Android 4.2 in the Name row from **OS**

499.99 in the Price row from **Phones**

How would I construct the query so that the sentence "Samsung Galaxy S3 16GB - Android 4.2 - £499.99?

Sorry for the lengthy post and thanks for any help/answers I receive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would I construct the query so that the sentence "Samsung Galaxy
>   S3 16GB - Android 4.2 - £499.99?

```
select  concat(m.Manufacturer, ' ', p.Model, ' ', p.StorageSize, ' - ',
            o.Name, ' - ', p.Price)
from    Phones p
join    Manufacturer m
on      p.ManufacturerID = m.ManufacturerID
join    OS o
on      p.OSID = o.OSID
```

Answer (score 1):

basically you need to join the tables,

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*, c.*  -- select only the columns you want.
FROM    Phones a
        INNER JOIN Manufacturer b
            ON a.ManufacturerID = b.ManufacturerID
        INNER JOIN OS c
            ON a.OSID = c.OSID
-- WHERE    .... put the condition here ...
```

You can also use [**CONCAT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) (or [**CONCAT_WS**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)) if you want the sentence will be generated on the query, all you can also do it on your front-end.

To fully gain knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Other Link(s)

- [More MySQL String Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html)

Comment: oh, supply an alias on @Andomar 's query, `SELECT CONCAT(....) sentence FROM...` and on your php script retieve `sentence` so you can display the value.

Comment: i'm back. can you post the whole php code along with your question soit can be easily viewed?

Comment: @user1762928 see Mahmouds'sAnswer `:D`